# Put date range to array

Tags: javascript, arrays, date, datepicker

I have two JQuery datepicker on my page, I want to put all the days between the two dates to an array.

How Can I work it out?
Here is my snippet:

```
function mennyi() {
var dtFrom = document.getElementById('arrival').value;
var dtTo = document.getElementById('departure').value;
var dt1 = new Date(dtFrom);
var dt2 = new Date(dtTo);
var diff = dt2.getDate() - dt1.getDate();
var days = diff;
alert(dtTo);
document.getElementById("nights").innerHTML = days + " nights"; {
   $('#arrival').datepicker({ dateFormat: 'dd-mm-yy' }).val();
   $('#departure').datepicker({ dateFormat: 'dd-mm-yy' }).val();
var start = new Date(document.getElementById('arrival').value),
    end = new Date(document.getElementById('departure').value),

    currentDate = new Date(start),
    between = []
;

while (end > currentDate) {
    between.push(new Date(currentDate));
    currentDate.setDate(currentDate.getDate() + 1);
}

$('#lista').html(between.join('<br> '));};
return false;
}
function isNumeric(val) {
  var ret = parseInt(val);
};
```

Now it works, but the thing is how can I change the date format, before I put the string into the array?

Comment: We need more details in order to provide a possible answer... What have you tried so far?

Comment: If this is jQuery, why are you using `document.getElementById('arrival').value`?  You can use `$('#arrival').val()`.  In fact, you *should* actually just do `$('#arrival').datepicker('getDate')`!  This will return you a `Date` object.

Comment: May I suggest using a date library like [moment.js](http://momentjs.com/) for this task?

Comment: Yes, It returns, but in a wrong format (Sat Apr 05 2014 00:00:00 GMT+0200).

I wanna have it in the same format like in the textbox (05/04/2014)